# How to configure Docker tooling on Eclipse?

Tags: docker, windows, eclipse

The Eclipse plugin "Docker tooling" seems to expect the installation of Docker Machine, or a network connection.

But, on Windows 10 things seem different from what this plugin expects so I can't browse for the required executables.
Also, how could I find out the local network URL? docker info does not reveal this.

[image]

Comment: IIRC docker on Windows 10 doesn't require a linux VM anymore, so I assume the plugin can't find the docker-machine binary as it doesn't exist anymore. The plugin has to be updated to handle this case

Comment: Where do I get the "connect to docker daemon" dialog?

Answer (score 12):

Under Windows 10, you'll find the Docker Machine (`docker-machine.exe`) under: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin`

This is the value you need to put in the Docker Machine field.
You don't need to change anything for the VM Driver field as VirtualBox doesn't need to be installed when you use Docker for Windows.

Then you have to edit some setting of the Docker daemon to allow your Eclipse Docker plugin to connect to it:

1. First of all, check if the Docker daemon is running by clicking on the Task View button on the Windows taskbar.
2. Mouse over the Docker icon and the tooltip should say: Docker is running.
3. If it's running, right-click the Docker icon to open the Docker contextual menu and go to Settings.
4. In the General Tab, which you will land on by default, Make sure the 
   "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" checkbox is checked.
   (It isn't by default)

You can now edit your Docker Connection in Eclipse and do not need to search for a connection name, simply enter how you want to name it (ie. SomeDockerConnection) and check the "TCP Connection" radio button.

You can enter `tcp://localhost:2375` in the URI and click "Test Connection".
You should see a message appear to confirm that the ping was successful.

At this point you'll be able to see your containers and images in Eclipse's Docker Explorer perspective.

Comment: Worked fine. One addition though: The VM Driver field one must not leave unchanged (the dialog will flag that as error and refuse to close) - instead one simply has to empty that field. Apparently the empty string is a "valid" driver name and is happily accepted. On Windows what is meant by the "Docker icon" is the "Docker Desktop icon" but I guess that's pretty obvious.

Comment: I get:  "Ping failed:  Host name may not be null"

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

1. Docker Settings: General: Check box enable: "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS
2. Eclipse docker tooling: Connect to a docker daemon: TCP Connection: URI: tcp://localhost:2375

I am now able to see images and containers listed in the 'Docker Explorer' view of Eclipse.